# How do you wire up views in Silverlight and MVVM using a TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm

I am building a Silverlight app which comprises a TreeView of menu options in a lefthand column and a ContentView in a righthand column. The idea is that the `SelectedItemChanged` event of the TreeView will change the view in the content area.

What is the 'purest MVVM' way of achieving this?

My idea is to have a `TreeMenuView` and `TreeMenuViewModel` for managing the menu events, but after that I'm a bit lost. I could use an EventAggregator to send a message from the  `TreeMenuViewModel` to a `ContentViewModel' that would then set its current ContentView based on the message args- but surely that breaks MVVM, in the sense that a ViewModel shouldn't know about UI constructs like a View?

Am I missing something simple here?

How does a ViewModel layer drive the View selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `ShellViewModel` which had:

- `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> AvailablePages`
- `int SelectedPageIndex`
- `ViewModelBase CurrentPage`, which returns `AvailablePages[SelectedPageIndex]`

Your `ShellView` can be anything you want. If you want to display your `AvailablePages` in a `TreeView`, then go ahead. Just remember to bind `SelectedIndex` to `` `SelectedPageIndex ``

In your case, I would create a `DockPanel` with a `TreeView` on the Left bound to `AvailablePages`, and a `ContentControl` on the right with `ContentControl.Content` bound to `CurrentPage`

**Edit**

Here's an example

```
<DockPanel>
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Right"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailablePages}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPageIndex}">
    ...
    </TreeView>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Then use `DataTemplates` to define how the ContentControl containing `CurrentPage` will look

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HomePageViewModel}" />
         <local:HomePageView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomerViewModel}" />
         <local:CustomerView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Rachel, thanks, that makes sense. Can I just clarify, where does the view selection / binding actually occur? In your description, if I have understood correctly, `ContentControl.Content` is bound to a ViewModelBase instance (CurrentPage) - should this not be bound to a View? I'm sure there's something simple I'm not getting here :)

Comment: @Malcom I added some sample code to my answer. The ViewModel contains the actual application state and navigation, while the View is simply a pretty UI that lets the user interact with the ViewModel. I usually use DataTemplates to associate my Views with their ViewModel

Comment: I'm using Silverlight and DataTemplates don't appear to support the DataType property - any other ideas?

Comment: @Malcum I forgot about Silverlight... I usually use either a `DataTrigger` and custom `Converter`, or a `DataTemplateSelector` to determine what DataTemplate to display

Comment: I ended up using Prism's `DataTemplateSelector` and your technique above, but I had to use Silverlight 5 which supports the `DataType` property.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I give it a shot

in TreeMenuViewModel:

```
public string PropSelectedItem
{
get;
set;
}
```

in `TreeMenuView`:

`<TreeView  Context="{Binding TreeMenuViewModel}" Content="{Binding PropSelectedItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>`

in ContentViewModel:

```
public ViewModelBase PropSelectedItem
{
get
 {
switch(TreeMenuViewModelStatic.PropSelectedItem)
{
  case "Booo": return typeof(View1);
  case "Foo": return typeof(View2);
}


  }
private set;
}
```

in ContentView:

`<ContentControl Context="{Binding TreeMenuViewModel}" Content="{Binding PropSelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>`

and you need a value convertor here

Comment: To convert the string to a view? I think I get where you're going with this, if I understand, your TreeView sets the selected item in the TreeViewModel (as, say, some string value "MenuItem1"), then your ContentViewModel exposes that item to the ContentView which loads the appropriate view control after converting the string value - is that right?